# Cannot read property 'overview' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, k-fold

I got the following error

> Cannot read property 'overview' of undefined

I cannot figure out what this is.

```html
<template>
  <tr v-for="(row, fold) of perFold" :key="fold">
    <td>{{ fold + 2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.correct }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.incorrect }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.accuracy.toFixed(2) }}%</td>
  </tr>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    perFold () {
      let data = this.result[this.attr].knn

      let perFold = []

      for (let i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
        let label = (i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i;
        let fold = data[`fold-${label}`]
        perFold.push(fold[fold.overview.bestAttr])
      }

      return perFold
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then in the browser, I get the following error

> TypeError Cannot read property 'overview' of undefined

When I comment this line

```js
perFold.push(fold[fold.overview.bestAttr])
```

I then do not have any error, but the results expected in my browser are empty.

Comment: Formatted to make it readable to a minimal degree.

Comment: `fold` is in some cases falsy (null, undefined), hence why you cannot access `overview` here.

Comment: I'm not really sure about the actual thing you're trying to achieve here, it could be nice to have an explanation of what is attended an probably also a [repro] if you want to have this one improved.

Answer (score 0):

```
        perFold.push(fold[fold[i].overview.bestAttr])
```

fold is a array. Because of that you need to specify loop index.

Comment: i got an error like this Cannot read property '1' of undefined, what should i do next? do you have any suggestion?

Comment: maybe if you write 'if(fold[i] != undefined)' at the beginning of your code the problem will be solved